# Why did Lord Beckett expect them to sing?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, at-worlds-end

In the *Pirates of the Carribean: At World's End* intro scene with the hanging, a soldier comes and says to Beckett that the people started to sing "Hoist the Colours". Beckett does not seem surprised and as if he was waiting for them to start singing.

Why was Beckett expecting such an action to happen?

Comment: because he was indeed waiting for them to start singing, note he says "Finally" in response. Beckett wants to totally eliminate piracy. The singing summons the remaining pirate lords to a central location whereupon he can wipe them out

Comment: @NKCampbell But the question is why. "He expected them to sing because he expected them to sing" doesn't really work.

Comment: From another stack; [Why does Lord Beckett say 'finally'?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/59654/why-does-lord-beckett-say-finally)

Comment: @Valorum Nice! I wasn't aware of that question. Should I close this one somehow as duplicate from other SE site?

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr - To be honest, I'd keep it open and ask (nay, demand!) a better source than a fan-written wiki.

Comment: @Valorum Well then... I demand a better source! :D

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr - Good for you. And I'll back a better quality answer up with a bounty (yarr!). Let the wiki-people shudder in their beds and keep away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's an unknown amount of time between *Dead Man's Chest* and *At World's End*, but during that time, Lord Beckett had carried out his "War Against Piracy", involving mass executions among the populace of Port Royal, and presumably other islands, of "all persons found guilty of piracy, or aiding a person convicted of piracy, or associating with a person convicted of piracy" combined with Beckett setting the *Flying Dutchman* and his armada against all known pirate ships. This war was committed with two goals in mind: obliterating the scourge of piracy and drawing out the nine Pirate Lords.

The first goal was more or less accomplished with the aid of the *Dutchman*, the armada, and the use of mass civilian executions as a deterrent; the second could only be achieved if the Pirate Lords convened in one location, i.e., Shipwreck Cove. And the Pirate Lords would only convene if, as Tia Dalma explained, "The song has already been sung. The Brethren Court is called." So when the people did begin to sing "Hoist the Colours", Beckett acknowledged that his second goal was finally coming into his grasp.

So Beckett was waiting for them to sing because he was, literally, waiting for the song to be sung, signaling a convocation of the Brethren Court and, for him, a means of wiping out the pirates' leadership in a single fell swoop.

Comment: Can you offer any additional evidence that this is what Beckett meant?

Comment: @Valorum Only by way of referencing the film itself. Beckett's war against piracy was all pretty straightforwardly portrayed, his (unsuccessful) deal with Will Turner to get a man inside Shipwreck Cove and betray the pirates with his armada following behind supports his endgame goal of wiping out the nine lords. There is also a suggestion that the song caused the literal piece of eight coins seen in the film to resonate as a signal to call the lords through some magic or other; I neglected to mention that in my answer.

Comment: I wonder if there is any lore behind the pieces and how they were made to summon the lords. It's not Tia Dalma who made them I think.

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr Behind the Pirate Lords' "Nine Pieces of Whatever We Happened to Have In Our Pockets at the Time", I think there's some in-universe lore or backstory for each and every one, but for the coins? Only thing I can think of is "The bell has been raised from its wat'ry grave/Do you hear its sepulchral tone?/A call to all, pay heed the squall,/And turn your sails to home"; maybe the coins were from a sunken treasure or some such, imbued with a magical ability to resonate across the seas. But that's just my speculation, I've not read anything that confirms any particular lore there.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 I really like that thought and it'd certainly match the rest of the universe with Aztec gold, Leon's ship, etc.

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr If you haven't read it, pick up a copy of "The Price of Freedom"; it's the only full-length novel in the PotC universe and has a lot of Capt. Jack's backstory in it, plenty of magic, and also features Beckett as a primary antagonist, leading up to why he hates Jack so much. Unfortunately it seems to now have a slight canon conflict with *Dead Men Tell No Tales*, but it's still fully worth reading.